# How to make Toolbar not null?

Tags: android, authentication, toolbar

My app has two activities, the main one is working well but when opening the login one it crashes with the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Here's the fragment of my code referred to the toolbar (It's basically the login activity + the toolbar I want to add):

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
  Toolbar toolbar;    

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.mainmenu);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Toolbar and menu are working well on my main activity. Toolbar is also in the XML layout for the login activity.

Comment: post your activity_login xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference...
```

This NPE intimate you to first of all set the toolbar

You are not setting the toolbar..First of all set it...
Do like this...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
   // toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.mainmenu);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

you don't need to use toolbar.inflateMenu() because the Toolbar is acting as your ActionBar. The only time you need to call toolbar.inflateMenu() is when you are using the Toolbar as a standalone widget. You can handle menu item click events by using the following lines of code...

```
toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
        new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle menu item click event here
                return true;
            }
});
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you! Now it's working but it's not inflated with the menu, why?

Comment: @DanielViañoSo inflateMenu  only working for toolbars that are not set as ActionBar

Comment: Thank you! I was also forgetting onCreateOptionsMenu, now it's all working

Comment: @DanielViaño..Mine pleasure...Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);` before `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: This was the problem, but now it's not inflated with the menu

Comment: use onCreateOptionsMenu()